# I am using graph walker tool. I like to know in this tool can two child edge can be excuted in parallel

Tags: java, rest, graphwalker

If their is a Parent edge A, and two children edges B and C. If condition is true for both B and C, can it be executed in parallel. I am using REST API to execute it.

Comment: Your question is too broad and very much unclear. No idea what you think we could be telling you upon such input.

Answer (score 1):

No, using GraphWalker, edges B and C cannot execute in parallel.